# JavaFX progress bar for complex background Task

Tags: javafx, progress-bar, task

How can I implement ProgressBar related 'updateProgress' related logic for indicate over roll performance of the complex background Task as follow. 
That mean that Task related service method is so complicated and that will be hard to go step by step detail with that method and implement the 'updateProgress' related logic. 
If any one has some idea please let me know. Thanks.

```
@FXML 
private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Autowired
private DataExportService dataExportService;

private List<Device> deviceList; // User selected device list for export 

/*
 * Export user selected data
 */ 
@FXML 
public void doExport() {

 // Defile the data export concurrent Task
 final Task taskExport = new Task<Void>() {

      @Override protected Void call() throws Exception {

          if(deviceList.size() > 0) {

             try {
                    // How can I implement ProgressBar related 'updateProgress' logic in here ?
                    // Note: It is so hard to implement ProgressBar related indicator on in side the 
                    //       'exportData()' methods because it is too complicated and it had several 
                    //        steps ex: Filter Device related all data, Build a SQL script,
                    //                  Write SQL Script to file etc.  

                    dataExportService.exportData(deviceList);

             } catch (DataExportException e) {
                    logger.error(e.getMessage());
             }

           }

          return null;
      }
 };

 // Set task property to ProgressBar
 progressBar.progressProperty().bind(taskExport.progressProperty());

 // Start data export task
 new Thread(taskExport).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making everything alright, but you are missing the call of `updateProgress()`.
Here is a sample Code:

```
Task t = new Task() {
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        int maximum = 20;
        for (int i = 0; i < maximum; i++) {
            // Here you update the progress each time
            updateProgress(i, maximum);
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

Happy Coding,
Kalasch

Comment: Hi Kalaschni. Thanks for the reply. Issue is how we can calculate maximum value as 20 and how we combine (synchronise) this update progress bar functionality with exportData service method. Thanks.

Comment: You know the maximum already i thought(deviceList.size)... by the way, you can check if a list is emtpy by `list.isEmpty()`.